# Nginx tomcat throw Broken pipe error

Tags: tomcat, nginx, broken-pipe

Nginx + tomcat, often reported Broken pipe mistakes in the tomcat write back the time, the stack shows errors in sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0 was thrown, the time variable, when a large number of visits thrown, Nginx and Tomcat are basically the default configuration

Answer (score 0):

I may have found the answer, I found a lot of nginx error code for the 499 error, the error code mean client has closed connection, that may be due to slow response, the customer closed the browser

Comment: Did you consider adding the NGINX `proxy_read_timeout` directive?